# How can I disable individual buttons on a flutter togglebutton widget?

Tags: flutter

So... I have a togglebutton widget [1|2|3|4], but if another widget is checked, I need to disable some of those buttons (eg, if I'm connecting to a Tile instead of a Frob, I need to disable 2 & 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play with Visibility to hide or not the widgets you want

Comment: So... it looks like I need to have 2 togglebuttons (one disabled/grayed, one not) for each actual togglebutton and swap them out with an if statement in the Scaffold?

Comment: If the if condition helps you to hide both buttons, then perfect you do the same validation and that's it

Comment: Gotcha.  For future readers, you can just stack togglebuttons on each other...

Answer (score 1):

I found that the best way is to have the a function that returns ToggleButtons widget based on certain input parameters. So the function returns ToggleButton widgets whatever number of toggle buttons you want. In case you want 3 buttons, you would pass in a list of 3 bools, take that list and build the ToggleButtons widget with only 3 buttons...and so on. And/Or you can have a condition that builds different ToggleButtons widget based on a certain parameter:

```
         ToggleButtons toggleButtons(
              {required StateSetter setState,
              required List<bool> isSelected,
              required String nameOfButtons}) {
            if (nameOfButtons == "shortList") {
            // return ToggleButtons widget that only has 3 Toggle Buttons
              return ToggleButtons(...);
            } else {
            // return ToggleButtons widget that only has 2 Toggle Buttons
             return ToggleButtons(...);
             }});
```

Visibility will simply hide the content of the toggle button but still allow a user to press that button. Also if you have an outline on your toggle buttons, the inside will just be blank but.